# Is it permissible to give Zakat in Islamic TV?

Tags: zakat

A well known Islamic TV is saying that it is fully OK and encouraging everybody to give Zakat in this TV channel. Is giving Zakat to Islamic channel should be the first choice?

Answer (score 1):

No, because our neighbour have more rights to receive our zakat if they were categorized as those who can receive zakat. What I can prefer is that you give to the nearest to you, either it through a zakat organizer, or you go there by yourself.

This is my personal statement as I dont have strong dalil for this.

Wallahuallam

Comment: Please, try to include reference, or the answer is opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

No, as I support and would like to add the following to AdityaPurwa's answer

> They ask you, [O Muhammad], what they should spend. Say, "Whatever you spend of good is [to be] for parents and relatives and orphans and the needy and the traveler. And whatever you do of good - indeed, Allah is Knowing of it. (Qur'an 2:215)

Also, I would prefer to go in the order mentioned in the verse.

May the creator guide us all.